# When right shift operation >> shift sign bit and when it not?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, signed

My question is why `a>>1` shift sign bit, but not `(a & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1` ?

**Code snippet**

```
int a = 0xaaaaaaaa;
std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
getBits(a);
std::cout << sizeof(a>>1) << std::endl;
getBits(a >> 1);
std::cout << sizeof(a & 0xaaaaaaaa) << std::endl;
getBits(a & 0xaaaaaaaa);
std::cout << sizeof((a & 0xaaaaaaaa)>>1) << std::endl;
getBits((a & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1);
```

**result**

```
4
10101010101010101010101010101010
4
11010101010101010101010101010101
4
10101010101010101010101010101010
4
01010101010101010101010101010101
```

Comment: The shift operation obeys the signedness of the left argument. So you should question the type of `a` and that of `a & 0xaaaaaaaa`.

Comment: _"For negative a, the value of a >> b is implementation-defined (in most implementations, this performs arithmetic right shift, so that the result remains negative)."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a >> 1` is boring. It's simply implementation defined for a `signed` type for negative `a`.

`(a & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1` is more interesting. For the likely case of your having a 32 bit `int` (among others), `0xaaaaaaaa` is an `unsigned` literal (obscure rule of a hexadecimal literal). So due to C++ type promotion rules `a` is converted to an `unsigned` type too, and the type of the expression `a & 0xaaaaaaaa` is therefore `unsigned`.

Makes a nice question for the pub quiz.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal, especially the "The type of the literal" table.

Comment: According to the reference, 0xaaaaaaaa can't fit in `int`. So it has type `unsigned int`. The rule is not obscure.

Comment: Indeed, for a 32 bit `int` you're correct. Methinks though that only a small proportion of C++ programmers know this.

Comment: @crvv I think the thing that throws most people is that using a unsigned type only applies to hex to octal literals.  If a decimal integer literal is too big for `int` it picks the next larger signed integer where as hex and octal will go unsigned if it fits and if not then the next larger signed integer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Absolutely. I wonder how many folk know what the rule will be / is for a binary literal?

Comment: @Bathsheba Probably not many.  In my C++14 draft binary literals are not even covered in the table.  I had to check [this C++17 draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#tab:lex.type.integer.literal) to see it behaves the the same as octal and hex literals(makes sense I guess).

Comment: BTW, I updated the cppreference page table to include binary bases.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't have the courage to edit cppreference ;-)

Comment: I didn't know that having a prefix changes the behaviour, the rule is quite obscure to me. I don't quite understand the reasoning behind this though, why is the un-prefixed version not allowed to behave as such too?